# how to perform two task in the backgroudworker process in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backgroundworker

I have to do two task parallelly in the backgroud worker process in the asp.net.

The following are the two task

1. Sent a email alert to support guys if any error event occurs in any of the server in a domain (All the time)
2. Sent the  status report of error messages for all the servers in a domain at a time for every 4 hours or based on the user configuration.

I have already implemented the first task through the background worker process (

Now I want to implement second one and that fetch the data from the database for every 4 hours or user configured.

Please find the below are source code that i have used for implementation.

```
      protected void Application_Start()
      {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
               new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(); 

    }


    private static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        GetEmailAlertData objGetEmailAlertData = new GetEmailAlertData();
        List<Email> lstEmaildetails = objGetEmailAlertData.GetEmailAlertDetails();
        SentinelAlerter objSentinelAlerter = new SentinelAlerter();
        foreach (Email objEmail in lstEmaildetails)
        {
            try
            {
       // I have implement first task           
                objAlerter.SendAlert(objEmail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement the second task in the same background worker process.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Task Scheduler, its easy and will sort your issues out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . i dont have idea how to implement the task scheduler. Do you have any links that how to use the task schedular in the asp.net mvc environment. If you any please share it here.

Comment: Its not related to MVC, basically you need to have console Application.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task